# How to get Ubuntu to recognize new installed Pandoc version?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, pandoc

I want to install a new `pandoc` version. I followed the procedure outlined [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html).

```
mark@server:~$ sudo cabal install pandoc pandoc-citeproc
```

This worked out. But when checking on the installed version I get

```
mark@server:~$ pandoc -v
pandoc 1.12.2.1
```

This is not the newest one, although, when trying to rerun the above installation command I get another version info:

```
All the requested packages are already installed:
pandoc-1.13.2
pandoc-citeproc-0.6
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

How do I get Ubuntu to run the latest install version? This might be a simple Ubuntu question (well I am new to Linux) but I do not understand how I can get Ubuntu to see the new pandoc version.

Comment: Cabal not affect the archive of ubuntu packages. You need to move generated binary to desired path for execution, and uninstall manually the system package.

Answer (score 1):

Cabal not affect the archive of ubuntu packages. You need to move generated binary to desired path for execution, and uninstall manually the system package.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on that, so newbees will understand (i.e. locations, paths etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc is written in the Haskell programming language. Cabal is a sort of package manager for Haskell programs. If you install anything with Cabal, the binaries end up in *`$HOME/cabal/bin/`*.

However, very likely your *`PATH`* environment variable is not pointing to that directory, or not pointing at it *before* other directories.

You should try the following in a terminal:

```
PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH
export PATH

pandoc --version
```

This should work. If it does, put the first two lines into your *`$HOME/.bashrc`* file, right at the end.